# If a node is replaced in Cassandra, will data automatically replicate to that node?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am running a 3-node Cassandra cluster with a replication factor of 3.  I recently had to replace one of the nodes.  Will the data existing in the other two nodes automatically replicate to the new node or will I have to manually do it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in 2.x, yes. If the auto_bootstrap configuration option isn't in the cassandra.yaml file, or it's set to True, then it will stream all of the data it's now responsible for as soon as it's online. If auto_bootstrap is set to False, then it will *not* until you call nodetool rebuild to do so.

As noted by the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html) however, there's a final step if you allow it to stream the data automatically:

> After all new nodes are running, run nodetool cleanup on each of the previously existing nodes to remove the keys that no longer belong to those nodes. Wait for cleanup to complete on one node before running nodetool cleanup on the next node.
>
> Cleanup can be safely postponed for low-usage hours.

If you do not run cleanup, then all of the old bits of data (the ones that got moved to the new node) will remain on the old 3 nodes.

Edit: Also, failed to mention in the post, make sure that you have a seed set in the seed list. Otherwise it won't know where to look for the data, of course.